# I can't customise my Django forms using widget tweaks for an app

Tags: django, python-3.x

I installed pip3, installed Django-widget-tweaks and add widget_tweaks in INSTALLED_APPS[] in settings.py.

When I run the server, I'm getting the error:

> -ImportError: No module named 'widget_tweaks'

[image: error image]

Comment: Which version of python is used to run django? Python3?. Is the package installed locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the `pip3` script has installed django-widget-tweaks into a different version of Python than the one you're using to run Django. You may have multiple versions of Python 3 installed on your machine.

Try installing django-widget-tweaks using the same version of Python that you're using to run Django:

```
/path/to/python -m pip install django-widget-tweaks
```

Obviously make sure `/path/to/python` is the version you're using to start  the Django server.